# Showing that the graph of $\frac{\cos(\pi x/2)}{1-x^2}$ decreases over the interval $(0,2)$.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How would one justify the behaviour of the graph of 
$$\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}{1-x^2}$$ 
over the interval $(0,2)$?

More precisely, how can it be shown that the graph is decreasing over that interval?

Comment: Use Latex please...to show that you would have to take the first dervative and show that it is always negative in that interval. But that function is not decreasing in (0,2)...it oscillates

Comment: I’m sorry, I made a typo, it was supposed to be pi/2, not pi/4. Also, from the derivative it’s quite hard to determine it being negative.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $f(x)$ takes the following form
\begin{equation}
 f'(x) = \frac{g(x)}{(1-x^2)^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 g(x) = -\frac{\pi}{2} \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}x)(1-x^2)+2x( \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}x))
\end{equation}
**PS: The function $f(x)$ is not defined at $1$**

Since the denominator of $f'(x) > 0$ on $[0,1[ \cup ]1,2]$, we will study $g(x)$. Get it's derivative
\begin{equation}
 g'(x) = -\frac{\pi^2}{4} \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}x)(1-x^2)
 +
 \pi x \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}x)
 +
 2\cos (\frac{\pi}{2}x)
 -\pi x \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}x)
\end{equation}
which is 
\begin{equation}
 g'(x) = -\frac{\pi^2}{4} \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}x)(1-x^2)
 +
 2\cos (\frac{\pi}{2}x)
\end{equation}
Factorize to get
\begin{equation}
 g'(x) = [-\frac{\pi^2}{4}(1-x^2)
 +
 2]\cos (\frac{\pi}{2}x)
\end{equation}
You could further factorize as 
\begin{equation}
 g'(x) = \big(x - \sqrt{1 - \frac{8}{\pi^2}} \big)\big(x + \sqrt{1 - \frac{8}{\pi^2}} \big)\cos (\frac{\pi}{2}x)
\end{equation}

---

### On the interval $[0,1]$

In the interval $[0,1]$, we know that both $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $x + \sqrt{1 - \frac{8}{\pi^2}}$ are positive. So in $[0,1]$ the sign of $g'(x)$ depends on $x - \sqrt{1 - \frac{8}{\pi^2}}$. Obviously we get that $g'(x) < 0$ in $[0,x_0]$ and $g'(x) > 0$ in $[x_0,1]$ where $x_0 = \sqrt{1 - \frac{8}{\pi^2}}$. So there is a minimum at $x_0$. But $g(0) = g(1) = 0$. So $g(x) < 0$ in $[0,1]$.

---

### On the interval $[1,2]$

In the interval $[1,2]$, we have that both $x + \sqrt{1 - \frac{8}{\pi^2}}$  and $x + \sqrt{1 + \frac{8}{\pi^2}}$ are positive so the sign of $g'(x)$ depends on $\cos \frac{\pi}{2}x$ which is negative in $[1,2]$. Hence, $g(x)$ is decreasing decreasing in $[1,2]$, but $g(1) = 0$, hence $g(x)$ is also negative in $[1,2]$.

---

### Concluding on $[0,2]$

We conclude that in $[0,2]$, 
\begin{equation}
 g(x) \leq 0
\end{equation}
Hence $f(x)$ is decreasing in $[0,2]$, excluding $x = 1$.